# Angular.js - Slicing a json request according to user input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am a beginner at Angular.js and am currently going through the [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07). I decided to try making the number of phones displayed changeable by the user. In my controller:

```
function PhoneListController($http) {
  var self = this;
  self.orderProp = 'age';

  $http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
    self.phones = response.data.slice(0, self.displayNum); 
  });
}
PhoneListController.$inject = ['$http']; //services to inject for each parameter in PhoneListController
```

I slice the response data that I get from the server according to the displayNum input by the user. I'm sure that displayNum is updated in the model, however it doesn't slice the json as I expected it to. Is the http request only made once at the start?

The relevant section of my template:

```
<p>
  Number of phones displayed:
  <input ng-model="$ctrl.displayNum" />
</p>
...
<ul class="phones">
  <li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp">
    <span>{{phone.name}}</span>
    <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
<p>display num: {{$ctrl.displayNum}}</p>
```

The `display num: {{$ctrl.displayNum}}` at bottom updates according to the number input in `<input ng-model="$ctrl.displayNum" />`, but the list does not change size. If I hardcode a value in for `self.displayNum` in the controller the list is sliced correctly when I refresh the page, but changing the value in the input does nothing to the list.

Comment: you should call `http` service again after updating `displayNum` model.

Comment: Could you please expand on that? How would I call http again? Is there a way of checking if the model has changed?

Comment: See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: That worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Alexander-Bolzhatov, I simply put the http request in a change function, called by ng-change in the template.

```
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
    self.phones = response.data; 
  });

  self.change = function(){
    $http.get('phones/phones.json').then(function(response) {
      self.phones = response.data.slice(0, self.displayNum); 
    });
  };
```

Template code:

```
Number of phones displayed:
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.displayNum" ng-change="$ctrl.change()"/>
```